# Custom URL's for custom post type

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am facing an issue regarding URL of the custom post type.
I have created a custom post type called 'Methods'.

So I've added "The Lorem Method" and assign this as a parent to week 1 method.
After that, I've added Day 1 and assign week 1 as a parent to this and list goes on.
Now, at dashboard structure is looking like this

-The Lorem Method 
-- Week 1 
---- Day 1
---- Day 2
---- Day 3
---- Day 4
---- Day 5

-- Week 2
---- Day 1
---- Day 2
---- Day 3
---- Day 4
---- Day 5

-The Ipsum Method
-- Week 1
---- Day 1
---- Day 2
---- Day 3
---- Day 4
---- Day 5

-- Week 2
---- Day 1
---- Day 2
---- Day 3
---- Day 4
---- Day 5

I know slug of two post item could not be same, is there any way to get the permalink to be like this

the-lorem-method/week-1/day-2
the-ispum-method/week-1/day-2

the-lorem-method/week-2/day-3
the-ispum-method/week-2/day-3

Comment: As of now what is the url structure you are getting ?

Comment: As of now, I have to make different slug for methods, weeks and days

the-lorem-method/tlm-w1/tlm-d2
the-ipsum-method/tim-w2/tim-d3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is that **there is not a way to do this**, unfortunately. Once a slug is used, it's used - even across Post Types.

You might have luck using something like the [Custom Permalinks](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-permalinks/) plugin, but it's not native WordPress functionality (and likely will never make it into WP Core)